# splitting text into array or splitting an array into more arrays

Tags: arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am quite new to working with arrays in snowflake (and dbt).
I am splitting out vendor names that I have when they are filled in as join names in our front end. Now, I get them split (see the example below), but I would like to know if it is possible to split an already split array or another function I can use to split the text.
In the example below, the first 3 records are split correctly, but the following three, is not being split correctly, and this is where I would appreciate input.
The simple case statement I am using at the moment is:

```
,case
            when upper(vendor_name) like '% AND %' then split(upper(vendor_name), ' AND ')
            when vendor_name like '%&%' then split(upper(vendor_name), ' & ')
        else array_construct(upper(vendor_name))
        end as arr_vendor_name
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

- Replace " & ", " AND ", ", " for ",".
- Then split on ",".

```sql
split(
  replace(replace(replace(vendor_name, ' AND ', ','), ' & ', ','), ', ', ',')
  , ','
)
```

Bonus: You won't need the `case` anymore, and the `array_construct` goes away too.

Comment: or slightly safer replace `AND` with `&` and then split on that, that way you don't turn valid comma's into a split point.